# Can ec.js be proxied with server side gtm?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Was wondering if only gtm.js and analytics.js can be proxied via gtm server? Can't find any information about this on google docs. Also, getting an error 404 when trying to fetch it with server side gtm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug where plugins/ua/ec.js will be fetched via https://your.domain/plugins/ua/ec.js

When that happens you have to pick that client request up and return the script manually (by writing a client template in on the server side container).

found a repo with the code example which shortened the hours I would had used otherwise.
credit: https://gist.github.com/mbaersch/e94e2499ea5bb761bf81878d815fd890#file-fix-ecjs-client-tpl
Here comes the important part:

```
const setResponseBody = require('setResponseBody');
const setResponseHeader = require('setResponseHeader');
const setResponseStatus = require('setResponseStatus');
const sendHttpGet = require('sendHttpGet');
const templateDataStorage = require('templateDataStorage');
const returnResponse = require('returnResponse');
const key = "ec.js";

if (require('getRequestPath')() === '/plugins/ua/ec.js') {
  require('claimRequest')();
  setResponseHeader('content-type', 'application/javascript');
  const cachedBody = templateDataStorage.getItemCopy(key);
  if (cachedBody) {
    setResponseBody(cachedBody);
    setResponseStatus(200);
    returnResponse();
  } else {
    sendHttpGet('https://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ec.js', (statusCode, headers, body) => {
      templateDataStorage.setItemCopy(key, body);
      setResponseBody(body);
      setResponseStatus(statusCode);
      returnResponse();
    });    
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stape.io have a File Proxy Client https://github.com/stape-io/file-proxy-client so you can proxy any file via your Server Side GTM container easily.

It does basically the same as what was described in the previous answer but more universal and ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side GTM doesn't proxy js like normal GTM does. It's mostly for proxying network requests.

If you wonder if it can send enhanced ecommerce events then yes, it can.

If you wonder if it can deploy anything on the site (that includes any js files), then no, it can't. It doesn't manifest on the front-end in any way at all. It can proxy files, but all that does is rewrites the endpoint that you still have to include in your DOM.

Use front-end GTM to deploy anything on the front-end.

Comment: That's wrong. Server-side GTM can serve both the client-side GTM file itself (there is a dedicated client for this) as well as the analytics script (if you check the "send to server" option in the configuration tag for GA4). It cannot rewrite the scripts, though, so I expect it cannot change the urls from with GA plugins are loaded.

Comment: Yeah, it can "serve" FE GTM, but that's far from how FE GTM does it. You still have to include it to the DOM manually, just using your server-side url as an endpoint. So if we call that "serving js", then we can say that any third-party web-server can "serve" js. Though by doing so, you will not only end up showing the fact that you use BE GTM, but also the location where your it is hosted, which takes away from its benefits.

Comment: I see now that I wasn't very clear in my question. But figured out the issue so will provide an answer.